# RxJS emit from source2 if source1 has timed out and when source1 is back emit from source1

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have an Observable source `source1` that emits values, if it does not emit anything for more than 2 seconds, I want to switch to a fallback source `source2`. And if `source1` emits again, I want to emit from it. And so on, indefinitely.

So far, I have the following

```
import { timeout, catchError, takeUntil, concat } from 'rxjs/operators';

declare const source1: Observable;
declare const source2: Observable;

source1.pipe(
    timeout(2000),
    catchError(() => {
      return source2.pipe(
        takeUntil(source1)
      );
    }),
    concat(source1)
).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

This almost works. If `source1` does not emit after 2 seconds, it emits from `source2` until `source1` emits again and then switch to `source1`. But there are 2 main flaws:

1. when `source1` emits again, the first emitted value is "caught" by `takeUntil` (`source1` is a hot observable) and won't be in `concat(source1)`
2. if `source1` stops emitting a 2nd time, I would like to have the same behaviour. With my implementation, it only works once.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found that solves my points 1 and 2 is the following

```
const source1HasStopped = source1.pipe(
  timeout(2000),
  catchError(() => of(1))
);

const fallback = source2.pipe(
  skipUntil(source1HasStopped),
  takeUntil(source1),
  repeat()
);

merge(source1, fallback).subscribe(console.log);
```

EDIT: Unfortunately, this creates a subscription leak because `takeUntil` is not last...

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could do this with sharing `source1` and then using `repeat` to resubscribe to the same chain (I didn't test it):

```
const shared1 = source1.pipe(share());

source1.pipe(
  timeout(2000),
  catchError(() => merge(source1, source2).pipe(
    takeUntil(source1),
  )),
  repeat(),
).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: Yes that worked, at least it solved my point 2. I still lose the first value that is emitted from `source1` once it emits again though

Comment: Can you try it with `catchError(() => merge(source1, source2).pipe(takeUntil(source1)))`? See update.

Comment: Yes I tried already with this syntax, it's the same, works as well. But once `source1` starts emitting again, the value is captured by `takeUntil(source1)`, so when we repeat, it will emits all the other values but the first one.

Comment: Actually don't need the `merge`, the `repeat` is enough to solve my point 2

Comment: I think, if you'd change catchError to `source2.takeUntil(source1).merge(source1.take(1))` -- it should help getting first value of the source1, when switching.

Example: https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/c14c6642424e485de51ab1c8c2d979be